# How to style icons in NextJs?

Tags: html, css, next.js, icons, png

Changing color of icon is not working in this way. Image is coming from "next/image"

```js
<Image 
  className={styles.icon} 
  alt="arrow" 
  src={ArrowIcon} 
/>
```

module.css

```
.icon {
  stroke: blanchedalmond;
  & path {
    stroke: blanchedalmond;
    color: blanchedalmond;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Hi you can add a new file "file.css" and import it in your js-file like ...

```
import "./file.css";
```

then I think, you can use

```
<Image 
   className="icon" 
   alt="arrow" 
   src={ArrowIcon} 
/>
```

in your css-file you use

```
.icon {your style...}
```

Regards

Jonas